# How to execute code inside performFetchWithCompletionHandler only when application is in active state?

Tags: ios, swift, background, fetch, appdelegate

I want to perform some action during some interval of time.But this should not occour when app is in background or inactive state.
I have implemented this as follows

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {


UIApplication.shared.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum)
   return true
}
```

And in the performFetchWithCompletionHandler

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, performFetchWithCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    print("Background fetch called")



        // foreground

    if (application.applicationState == .active)
    {

        //lines of code to perform



}
}
```

But when I tried simulating background fetch in simulator ,it is showing the following message

Warning: Application delegate received call to -application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler: but the completion handler was never called.

I tried removing the application state condition and it is working fine.But i want to perform these lines only when app is active and not in background or inactive state.How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the **completion handler** to the function. It should be called when the data fetch completed.

Insert this to your code if you have new data to display:

```
completionHandler(.newData)
```

...this if you have no data:

```
completionHandler(.noData)
```

...and this if the fetch failed:

```
completionHandler(.failed)
```